# Heroku deploy JAVA Maven dyno not running

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have a JAVA application which works perfectly when running locally. I am using IntelliJ IDEA IDE and the Heroku deploy configuration with the following command `heroku:deploy`, I also have a pom.xml file with the following snippet:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>discord-bot-uskompuf</appName>
                    <processTypes>
                        <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Bot</web>
                    </processTypes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My starting code is `<web>java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Bot</web>`

My main class is named Bot, when I go to compile to Heroku deploy the application successfully compiles and gets uploaded to Heroku and I receive a build success message. On my Heroku dashboard, I can see my dyn0 `web java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Bot` however it is always listed as OFF. Looking at Heroku logs just shows that my build has succeeded.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to enable dyno on heroku

Comment: Mark this as the solution

Comment: Need to wait 2 days